# php curl throwing 500 error

Tags: php, curl

The curl is giving me 500 error. How to fix 500 error ?

```
$msg='Phone:'.$_POST['phone'].',Email:'.$_POST['email'].',Message:'.$_POST['query'].''; // This is dynamic msg.  
$urlpara="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/sendsms/bulksms?username=xxx&password=xxxx&type=0&dlr=1&destination=xxxx&source=xxxx&message=".$msg."";    
$response = sentSmS($urlpara);

if($response){
    header('Location: thankyou.html');  
    exit;
}else{
    header('Location: thankyou.html');  
    exit;
}

function sentSmS($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's nice. What is your question?

Comment: `500` is a server error. So your server is encountering a problem. So either you add part of the code of your server that is necessary or we can't help you.

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong with this code, because 1) we don't know your  question, 2) we don't know anything about server where you send request.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Look to server logs it will help you.

Comment: Not the issue but `return $content; curl_close($ch);` ... the script will never get to `curl_close($ch);`

Comment: My question is why its throwing me 500 error ? want to remove that one.

Comment: all right. i will remove it update the code lets see what happen.

Comment: You don't "remove" an error, you fix the problem by learning about and understanding what you are doing.

Comment: Same here. Not working with last suggested script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `$content` in sentSmS function, from where you get it? maybe you want to return `curl_exec($ch)` ?

Answer (score 0):

try debug it:

```
function sentSmS($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'cUrl',
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 400,    // timeout on response - after 400s
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT  => true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => 0
    ];

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (empty($result)){
      $error = curl_error($ch);
      $errorNumber = curl_errno($ch);

      $exception = new \Exception('curl call error: '.$error, $errorNumber);
      throw $exception;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```